# problem on upload images in user specific folder by filemanager in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

please help me.
I'm trying to upload images to my website. I created folder for every user that registered in my site.
how can I change lfm.php file to upload every user their own images inside their own folder.
example user A images get upload inside A folder and user B images get upload inside folder B.

I change the lfm.php file image upload directory to photo.Auth:user()->id .. and it doesn't work . and cause a error. are any body can help me??

Comment: You may have missed something in the `confgi/lfm.php` configuration. Carefully read over the Filemanager readme file and check if your settings are correct. What you try to do won't work. Check out the original settings for the `'private_folder_name'` key. This is what you probably want to change. But you can't hardcode it. You'll have to create your own Class and direct the settings page there.

Comment: thank you so much. its worked. I did it. but I have new problem. I want upload images in small size. and when try to install intervention image , it does not work and Image class not found. can you help me to how I can install step by step intervention image resizer. what is requirement for me??

Comment: Have you created an alias for 'Image' in Config\app.php file?

Comment: I use https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image that can scale pictures on the users' browser before sending to the server. It's relatively easy to setup and ES6 ready (`promise()`). Intervention image is a great class, but it only works server-side. Have you added `'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,` to `config/app.php` Class Aliases? Always take your time to read through the setup/implementation readme file of classes/modules or on their website.

Comment: thank you so much. I did it. Its work. 